# linux man command in different languages

Tags: linux, man

I want view man pages in Russian. Is it possible to do this? If yes, what do I need to do? Can I install it just using apt-get? I tried to google, but didn't find an answer.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man` supports multiple languages, as long as the manpage you want to see has that language included.

First, check if you have a russian locale generated. Do `locale -a` and see if you get a russian one, for example `ru_RU.utf8`. If you don't, edit `/etc/locale.gen` as root, un-comment the one you want and run `locale-gen` as root.

You will then be able to ask for a manpage in russian with

> LANG=ru_RU.utf8 man man

provided that `ru_RU.utf8` is returned by `locale -a`.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 15.10, use `man -Lru [name]`<ref>http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43384/localization-of-man-pages-on-linux-ubuntu</ref> instead.